# GUI Database - Connecting with Excel or Access

Tags: database, excel, ms-access, user-interface

i am planning on making a database that has a GUI (Graphic users Interface). That connects with either MS Excel or MS Access Which will do:

- Add new rows
- Search category
- Print in a form

Can you tell me which way to do it? Is Java my answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I hate to sound like a DB snob but **Excel is not a database**.  I wish people would stop trying to use it as such.  It's a spreadsheet application, **not** a database.

As for GUI, what environment are you going to run it in?  Why not just use Access' GUI and stick with it?  If you have an Intranet (assuming you're developing this for a company you're employed by), consider using C#.  If you're going to design a database that you want to use as a "stand alone" (i.e. one that you want to compile and distribute), Visual Basic isn't a bad way to go, nor is C#.

Ultimately, use something you're comfortable with.  If you know anything at all about VBA (the language used by Access, Excel and Word), Visual Basic is pretty easy to learn.

Comment: I have learned how to use Java but only the very basic. Don't worry you don't sound like a DB snob, I should of known that Excel is not a Database (Actually i knew it but i was hoping it was.)
As i don't know how to use C#, since I never used it before. I'll go with Visual Basic as you said. All i needed was to know which road i should take, so I will not go completely blind to make what i have to.
Thank you.